# How to retain the object which runs async task in another object and get the async task run successfully?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks

- I have two objects of each ClassA and ClassB respectively.
- ClassB contains a method which is big which I want to run async in the background or say other async thread.
- I have object of ClassA retained properly, however, I have a property of object of ClassB in object of ClassA. This helps me to keep the object of ClassB retained till its async method finishes.
- Issue : When I run the following code on mainThread it runs ok, but when I put the long running method in async thread then objectB gets deallocated instantly and nothing happens.

  ```
   @interface ClassA : NSObject

   @property(nonatomic, strong) ClassB *objB;

   @implementation ClassA

   -(void)createAndExecuteB
   {
       self.objB = [ClassB getNewAndExecute];
   }


   @interface ClassB

   +(ClassB *)getNewAndExecute;

   @end

   @implementation ClassB

   -(void)timeConsumingTask
   {
      //statements
   }

  +(ClassB *)getNewAndExecute
  {
       ClassB * __block objB = [[ClassB alloc] init];

     //Here is my issue. If I remove this dispatch code and just call
     // the timeConsumingTask method, then everything works well (blocking
     // the UI thread for a while but completing the tasks properly).
     // but if I keep the dispatch code, then this object gets instantly
     // deallocated and nothing runs
          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0) ,^{
            [objB timeConsumingTask];
   });

   return objB;
   }
    @end
  ```

Comment: Why are you using __block?

Comment: I used __block so that the objB variable can be modified from the dispatch async's void block and also for calling the method "timeConsumingTask"

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 But you are not modifying `objB` inside a block so there is no reason to use `__block`. You need `__block` if you do something like `objB = ...` inside a block.

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 objB variable is a pointer - it won't be modified in block (at least it shouldn't be). If you modify objB's properties, there is no need to mark it as __block

Comment: I understand, but I am setting certain changes to objB from the async block in my actual code, hence, I kept the same here. As a note, even without keeping the __block, results into the same instant deallocation behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be working fine, so the problem must be somewhere that you're not showing us.

You could be

1. calling `[ClassB getNewAndExecute]` directly rather than through `[classA createAndExecuteB]`;
2. not retaining the A instance for the full duration of the task like you think you are;
3. calling `[classA createAndExecuteB]` multiple times on the same `ClassA` instance, which would overwrite the `self.classB` that you're trying to retain.

It is notable that you don't show what happens at the end of `timeConsumingTask`.  How does `ClassA` or whatever is retaining `ClassA` know that `timeConsumingTask` is complete?  That's the time that you have to release the `ClassB` instance so it's important.

Checking 1 should be easy.

To check 2, add a `dealloc` method to `ClassA` and `ClassB` and add `NSLog` statements or set breakpoints on them so that you can see when your objects are being deallocated.

To check 3, add an `NSLog` to `createAndExecuteB` so that you can see how many calls you're getting.

This is a good trick, printing the pointers of the objects so that you can see whether you're re-using instances by accident:

```
NSLog(@"%p %p", (void *)self, (void *)self.classB);
```

Comment: Well, the actual code is too much to paste up here. But, yes, I've added the dealloc method in ClassB and it is printed instantly. No multiple running of the methods occur. The objB is retained properly. As you see, if I just remove the dispatch_async, everything runs perfect. But, I placed the dispatch_async so that I do not block the UI thread. More in ObjB  there is a nsnotification which I fire and objA listens. I fire the notification after the timeConsumingTask by calling the dispatch_get_main_queue. :)

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 Did you check if classA is retained properly as suggested in 2)?

Comment: Yes Peter, it is retained. Basically in my actual code the classA is a singleton. So it lives throughout the app. :)